# "nice" keyword in c++?

Tags: c++

So I was doing some simple C++ exercises and I noticed an interesting feat. Boiled down to bare metal one could try out compiling the following code:

```
class nice
{
  public:
    nice() {}
};

int main()
{
  nice n;
  return 0;
};
```

The result is a compilation error that goes something like this:

```
<file>.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
<file>.cpp:11: error: expected `;' before ‘n’
<file>.cpp:11: warning: statement is a reference, not call, to function ‘nice’
<file>.cpp:11: warning: statement has no effect
```

And this was using regular g++ on Max OS X, some of my friends have tried in on Ubuntu as well, yielding the same result.

The feat seems to lie in the word "nice", because refactoring it allows us to compile. Now, I can't find the "nice" in the keyword listings for C++ or C, so I was wondering if anyone here had an idea?

Also, putting

```
class nice n;
```

instead of

```
nice n;
```

fixes the problem.

P.S. I'm a relative C++ newbie, and come from the ActionScript/.NET/Java/Python world.

**Update:**

Right, my bad, I also had an

```
#include <iostream>
```

at the top, which seems to be the root of the problem, because without it everything works just fine.

Comment: The root of the problem is not `#include <iostream>`, but `using namespace std`!

Comment: @Autopulated - I don't think it is namespace std, it is a clash with the global namespace.  <iostream> is pulling in <unistd.h> and it is conflicting with ::nice()

Comment: It sounds like it's the "std" namespace, as many people have said. Once you confirm that, please mark one of those answers as "accepted" (the green checkmark) rather than one that isn't really an answer.

Comment: This is why introductory texts shouldn't start people of with "using namespace std", just to save a few repetitive "std::"s.

Comment: It's not namespace std that is clashing, it is the global namespace.

Comment: @Duck see the edit to my reply below: `#include <iostream>` puts everything into `namespace std`, if it is compliant with the standard. (of course the Microsoft one may not be...)

Comment: Since nice() is not an ISO C++ function, there's no obligation on `iostream` to put it into namespace `std` rather than the global namespace. In fact, even for standard functions, there's no such obligation, with respect to C headers (i.e. if `iostream` includes `cstdio` - and it can - it's implementation-defined whether e.g. `printf` will be in global namespace, or in namespace std).

Comment: @ Pavel, yes there is! see the standard: Section 17.4.1.2.4!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a namespace problem but *not* with namespace std.  The header `<iostream>` is pulling in `<unistd.h>`

If you try

```
class nice
{
  public:
      nice() {};
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    nice n;

    return 0;
}
```

there is no problem.

Simply add

```
#include <unistd.h>
```

and you will get the "expected ‘;’ before ‘n’" error.  Namespace std does not enter the picture.

So the solution is the same as before - put class nice in its own namespace and it will not clash with the global ::nice().

Answer (score 17):

Maybe the problem is somehow caused by function `nice` in libc. It is similar to trying to name your class `printf`.

Answer (score 4):

`using namespace std`, by any chance?

Edit:

The standard says that standard headers define all their symbols in namespace std (see 17.4.1.2.4).
A footnote, however, also says that the <.h> variants dump their names into the global namespace - but of course no one should be using these ;)

Comment: The footnote refers to the `<stdio.h>` variants; the ones inherited from C. There is no .h variant of `<iostream>` in ISO C++. An implementation may provide one, though, as the headername <iostream.h> is not reserved by ISO C++

Comment: @MSalters yes, exactly: <iostream> isn't a c header, hence it does not put *any* symbols into the global namespace.

Answer (score 3):

Try this version:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace test
{
    class nice
    {
    public:
        nice() {}
    };
};

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    test::nice n;
    cout << "well I think this works." << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

In this case I've defined my own namespace `test`. Doing so, I can use whatever class names I like, including functions already defined like `printf`. The only things I can't re-use are reserved words like `int` or `namespace`.

Note: if you say:

```
using namespace test;
```

As well and refer to `nice` alone, you'll get this error:

```
nice.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
nice.cpp:18: error: reference to ‘nice’ is ambiguous
/usr/include/unistd.h:593: error: candidates are: int nice(int)
nice.cpp:7: error:                 class test::nice
```

Which I think explains nicely what's going on - nice now exists in two namespaces and the compiler can't work out which one you mean.

Comment: In case anyone is curious (as I was), here's some information about the function std::nice() http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Traditional-Scheduling-Functions.html#Traditional-Scheduling-Functions (scroll down to the bottom)

Comment: Yeah, niceness is a value used by the Linux kernel for scheduling purposes. It's just occurred to me that's what this is for...

Comment: nice() is *not* in std, it is global.

Answer (score 2):

It works fine for me.  Did you try the exact code you posted?

Comment: Right, no, I had a #include <iostream> at the top :) that's probably it.

Answer (score 0):

```
extern "C"
{
#include <unistd.h>
}
```